# IP tracing functions in django

Tags: django, session, ip

I'm not sure what subject this belongs to, basically. like sites like ipchicken.com and whatismyip.com that reveal your ip and server location just by visiting the page, I have a page which I would like to do the same. It is a simple one page website where the user visits and as soon as they viewed the page, I have their ip and server location logged in my database.
Building on this, I would also like to trace the visitor's digital footprint so that I can harvest profiles of my visitors. My question therefore is how would this be implemented in django and where is the best place to start learning how to do this. I am aware of sessions cookies and caches but haven't a clue how to implement them for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the visitor's IP with something like `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` and you can turn that into a *rough* location on a map with a geoip library like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/

But "build a digital footprint"? Not really sure where you're going with that. If you just want to be able to track all the pages a person goes to on your site, you'd be better off with  using a cookie.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the definition of digital footprint, but I was intending be able to see what they look at online outside of my site.

Comment: That's not really possible. Ad Networks are able to see what you visit across many sites (but not all sites) because they serve ads to many sites. Unless you can  convince a bunch of other sites to include your tracking code, then you can't people once they leave your site. The closest you can do is capture the Referer on their first hit, which will (usually) tell you what page they were on immediately *before* they clicked through to your site.

Answer (score -3):

(can be adapted from PHP to django)

To just show publicly the visitor's IP:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

To log to database:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sqlserver = 'localhost';
$sqlusername = 'database-name';
$sqlpassword = 'password'; //password to the user mentioned above
$con = mysql_connect($sqlserver,$sqlusername,$sqlpassword);
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db('database-name');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database-name`.`table-name` ...", $con);
?>
```